# How to bundle legacy js files with webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Suppose I have two files

a.js:

```
alert("hello from a.js");
```

b.js

```
alert("hello from b.js");
```

is there any way to bundle them with WebPack so that

1. I get both alerts synchronously as soon as bundle is loaded
2. alerts should be in the same order as declared
   "hello from a" and then "hello from b"

Answer (score 5):

Webpack natively supports CommonJS ( require / import ) and AMD style, and since yours are not falling into those categories, I believe you should look at the shimming modules section

https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/shimming-modules

This is from their header

> In some cases webpack cannot parse some file, because it has a
>   unsupported module format or isn't even in a module format. Therefore
>   you have many options to convert the file into a module.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else that comes looking, the new (webpack 4+) link to the docs on shimming is here: https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/

Answer (score 2):

For me personally, this webpack plugin was most helpful and headache free: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-merge-and-include-globally